# Windows Azure configuration management

Tags: azure

We have built a small MVC4 application using Azure Cloud Services. It has been deployed through Visual Studio. Now we are going add a test environment where the application should be tested, before being deployed into production.

I would like to have our CI server to build, test and create a deployable package, This package could then be deployed to any environment, providing correct configurations.

But I have not found a convenient way to do this. It is easy to build a package for a specific environment, with configuration transformations for .config and .cscfg files.

Is having the CI server to build a separate package for each environment the way to go, or have I missed something?

There are ways described how the web.config could be modified when the WebRole is starting, but this feels a bit hacky, and not the way the guys at Microsoft intended when creating Cloud Services.

Answer (score 0):

Using the CI server to deploy the specific configuration has been the easiest in my experience. I think using the Visual Studio "Build" section in Team Explorer is what your looking for.  We use [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) as our Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery server. In Visual Studio we've created Production and Testing build configurations. In the Build tab we've created a Continuous Integration Build which will kick off unit tests on every checkin, and a Continuous Delivery Build That will deploy newly tested checked in code on a regular schedule. These Build Events can be set to use a specific (Production/Testing) build configuration.